# What is the correct way to handle the ecosystem deployment file in terms of version control and file system?

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I have a ecosystem.json file for PM2 that handles apps, deployment, and environment variables. very similar to the example scripts on the [deployment documentation page](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/#getting-started).

I'm curious about best practices involving storing this file in version control and on the server's file system; seeing as it contains things like password and keys.

I have considered ignoring it from version control, however doing that means the deployment PM2 process won't work. Deploying without the ecosystem file in the repository means the post deploy script won't find it as it wasn't cloned to the machine.

> npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production

This means I am now using a private repository and checking in the ecosystem file. Is it possible to have a public repository and still use pm2 deployment?

Finally what are the best practices about having the ecosystem file on the file system? It seems that PM2 requires that it be there.

My understanding of env variables was that only the running processes know about them. Is this a misunderstanding? Is a file containing sensitive env variables okay to be left in the application code directory?

Should I add another line to the post-deploy script to delete the ecosystem file after running the application? Would that cause problems with things like restarting the processes or anything else?

> npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production && rm ecosystem.json